# Is there an equivalent of Android's LRUCache in Java?

Tags: java, android, caching, data-structures

I would like to use Android's [LruCache](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache) in my plain old non-Android Java projects. Is there an equivalent data structure in regular Java or do I have to roll out my own implementation?

Comment: If you need advanced functionality, there are dedicated libraries like [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regular Java you can do it with a `LinkedHashMap`, using the 3-argument constructor to make it access-ordered, and overriding `removeEldestEntry` to expire entries.